# Is it possible to choose which attributes are returned when calling github api?

Tags: github-api

I'm using the github v3 api (https://developer.github.com/v3/) to recover some information from a repository.

For exemple, I'm calling this: https://api.github.com/repos/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases

The reply is really verbose, giving me a bunch of informations I don't need

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases/485454",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases/485454/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases/485454/assets{?name}",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases/tag/1.3.2",
    "id": 485454,
    "tag_name": "1.3.2",
    "target_commitish": "develop",
    "name": "Save your settings",
    "draft": false,
    "author": {
      "login": "redwarp",
      "id": 1741661, ...
```

Is it possible to send a request that only fetch the url, tag_name and author for instance? Or should I just keep everything, and use only what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible currently -- use what you need.

Comment: Do you know that for sure? I mean, does this info comes from github or someone at github? If so, I'll accept your answer as "the one"